# Best approach to call web api from azure function

Tags: c#, azure, httpclient, azure-functions

I have a two blob-triggered Azure functions that are working perfectly (one is `v2` and the other `v1`). I have, in the other hand, a REST Web API application (that exposes methods to encrypt and decrypt a stream) published in my Azure Devops (still not deployed on Azure portal, actually, only code is added to an Azure Devops repository).

What I want to do is call the Web API application via HTTP calls (call encrypt or decrypt or whatever) from my Azure function to decrypt blob content.

No authentication needed.

In order of best practices, is it more suitable to make an API app from my Web API, or just deploy my Web API project as a web app to Azure? And why?

In other terms, what is the best way to call an API from my Azure function?

Can anyone provide me some code samples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you want to call `API` inside your `azure function` here is the code sample for your understanding:

In this Function I supplied a MPN number as Input which valid from a `3rd party API` and return `true` and `false` in response

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;


namespace HaithemKAROUIApiCase.Functions
{
    public static class HaithemKAROUIApiCaseClass
    {
        [FunctionName("HaithemKAROUIApiCaseFunction")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");


            try
            {
                // Convert all request param into Json object

                var content = req.Content;
                string jsonContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                dynamic requestPram = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PartnerMpnModel>(jsonContent);


                // Extract each param
                //string mpnId = requestPram.mpnId;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestPram.MpnID))
                {
                    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Please enter the valid partner Mpn Id!");
                }
                // Call Your  API
                HttpClient newClient = new HttpClient();
                HttpRequestMessage newRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("YourAPIURL?mpnId={0}", requestPram.MpnID));

                //Read Server Response
                HttpResponseMessage response = await newClient.SendAsync(newRequest);
                bool isValidMpn = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>();


                //Return Mpn status 
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new PartnerMpnResponseModel { isValidMpn = isValidMpn });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Invaild MPN Number! Reason: {0}", string.Format(ex.Message));
            }
        }
    }




   public class PartnerMpnModel
    {
        public string MpnID { get; set; }
    }


    public class PartnerMpnResponseModel
    {
        public bool isValidMpn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Request Format**

```
{
    "MpnID": "123456789"
}
```

If you still have any query feel free to share. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: run.csx(10,42): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please post your problem with new thread along with some more information so that it can be reproduced. I will answer there. Because this context different from your problem. Hopefully you got my point Thanks